# Emacs reselect region, as Vim shortcut 'gv' does

Tags: emacs

In vim, visual block can be recall by 'gv' command so that multiple commands can be applied easily.  (such as, comment out, then indent, then do_something_fun).

In Emacs, how can this be achieved?
[C-xC-x] only works when current cursor position stays where previous block ended.
If previous block was changed, the closest is to go through 'point-to-register' and 'jump-to-register'.

Just I am curious if there is an Emacs built-in command making this in one shot.

Comment: Aww, why go from vim to emacs?

Comment: Don't want to be in religious choice-of-editor debate.  2 years ago, I switched to Emacs, and I like it.

Comment: Could you describe what you mean in more detail? I'm not familiar enough with vim to know what you are asking for.

Answer (score 12):

If Transient Mark mode is off, the region is always active. If it's on (which it sounds like is your situation), you can set `mark-even-if-inactive` to non-nil to allow region commands to work while the region isn't highlighted.

However, note you also can cycle back through previous mark positions using `C-u C-SPC` -- this will pop the mark ring. Once you're back to where you want to be, C-x C-x will rehighlight the region you want. (It may take a little bit of playing with this feature to get a feel for it, but it's why I can't switch away from Emacs now.)

Comment: With this in mind, Emacs seems to be way more flexible than vi in this regard. However, C-x C-x should suffice in most situations like described by the OP.

Answer (score 10):

If I understand correctly what you are asking for, then you don't need to do anything. When you select a region in emacs, it stays selected until you select a new one. So you could select the region and then perform as many actions as you want.

Comment: Using Emacs 23(.0.93.1).  Thanks, but it didn't work as you mentioned.  I am selecting resion using CTRL-SPC for beginning, current-posision for the end.  Region highlights after the selection.  Applying a command makes this hightlight go away.  I assumed this deselects region.

Comment: @Raymond Try performing another action. The region is no longer highlighted but it is still selected.

Comment: It no longer works. Test the following with latest Emacs and with -q --no-splash option: select some lines, M-; to comment out the lines, then M-% to invoke replace and see that the replacement action is not restricted to the previously selected lines.

Comment: So in order to reselect the lines, `C-x C-x` needs to be pressed before `M-%`. With CUA mode on, that would be `C-u C-x C-x` instead of `C-x C-x`.

Comment: Jisang Yoo: Note that replacing in a region only applies to active regions in transient-mark-mode (i.e. when the region is highlighted). So this answer never applied to commands with this constraint; but it was (and remains) entirely valid for the rest. Your exchange-point-and-mark tip is certainly the best way to reactivate/highlight the region in most situations.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're looking for the secondary selection, which stays put even as the region might change. (It stays put until you move it.)

See:

- the Emacs manual, node `Secondary Selection`
- Emacs wiki page [Secondary Selection](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SecondarySelection)
- library [`second-sel.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/second-sel.el):

Answer (score 1):

Also narrow-to-region (CTRL-x n n )  applies every command from then on just to that region- you can't hurt the rest of the buffer, it doesn't even show. After done editing , widen (CTRL-x n w )to get back the whole buffer.
 CMM

Answer (score 0):

Since the answers here and for other similar SO questions didn't help for me (CUA-mode, Emacs 24, not only indent-rigidly), I continued searching and finally found a `reselect-last-region` defined in this [collection of custom function (starting line 670)](http://grapevine.net.au/~striggs/elisp/emacs-homebrew.el). That worked like a charm for me - and hopefully does for others still arriving here.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `evil-mode`, just press `gv` like in vim.